# Access server behind router with external ip (works well except from pc in same network)

Tags: networking, iis-7, router

Almost the same website problem as [this post found](http://www.astahost.com/info.php/Server-Router_t13159.html)

**server:** Windows 2008 with IIS7

**Router:** Dlink DIR-615

**Configured:** Port 80 forwarded, ddns OK

Shield Up: Port 80 test ok

Online Browser: PC outside network can access the website

And my **Problem:**

- PC outside private network - Access using external ip or ddns hostname: **OK**
- PC inside private network - Access using internal ip (192.168.0.x): **OK**
- From the server - Access using "localhost": **OK**
- PC inside private network - Access using external ip or ddns hostname: **failed**

Just wonder why pc in the same network can not access to web server using external ip while those external pc can do so? Well I found some points from the post above:

- **Such access confuse router**: well I can not get the point. Some said some DNS settings in router can fix that but I can not find how to do that
- **Change host table and map hostname to internal ip**: this of course works (even without internet connection) , just no difference from accessing with "192.168.10.x". Such solution make no sense, I want to access the server via internet to make sure what external user will get in their browser

Thanks advance for your help !